# Creating a trailing count on a table

Tags: sql, join, count, teradata

I have a table that has a list of various marketing emails that have been sent, who they have been sent to and the date they were sent.

I am trying to build a column that holds a value for how many contacts within the last 90 days have been sent to that customer.

I have been having trouble thinking about how to code this in SQL. Any suggestions would be really helpful!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Since this would change all the time, you probably would want to do a view based on a select instead of having a table itself.

Answer (score 0):

The **current_date()** might need a replacement according to your database.

```
select      customer
           ,count (*)   as contacts

from        mytable

where       contact_date >= current_date() - 90

group by    customer
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table structure as below.

```
MarketingEmails( CustomerID, Email, SentTo, SentDate );


SELECT CustomerId,
       Email,
       SentTo,
       SentDate,
       COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerID,Email ORDER BY SentDate ) AS 
       CountofContactsbyCustomerEmail
  FROM MarketingEmails
 WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),TO_DATE( SentDate ) ) >= 90;
```